# How to load pages inside split view content's frame passing parameters on UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

Here is my MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BibleApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Domain="using:BibleApp.Domain"    
x:Class="BibleApp.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RelativePanel>
            <Button Name="HamburgerButton" 
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                    Content="&#xE14C;" FontSize="14" 
                    Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
        </RelativePanel>

        <SplitView Name="MySplitView" 
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" 
                   OpenPaneLength="200" 
                   CompactPaneLength="34" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <ListBox Name="IconsListBox" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="IconsListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBoxItem Name="Biblia">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE128;" FontSize="18"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Bíblia" FontSize="12" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>

                    <ListBoxItem Name="PesquisarPalavraChave">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE11A;" FontSize="18"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Pesquisar palavra chave" FontSize="12" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>

                    <ListBoxItem Name="PesquisarAssunto">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE773;" FontSize="18"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Pesquisar assunto" FontSize="12" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Frame Name="MyFrame"/>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is it's code behind of MainPage:

```
private void IconsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyFrame = this.Frame;
    if (Biblia.IsSelected) { Frame.Navigate(typeof(View.BiblePage), bible);}
    else if (PesquisarPalavraChave.IsSelected) {Frame.Navigate(typeof(View.SearchWordPage));}
    else if (PesquisarAssunto.IsSelected) { Frame.Navigate(typeof(View.SearchMatterPage)); }    
}
```

Here is BiblePage OnNavigatedTo event:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{            
    bible = (Bible)e.Parameter;
}
```

The problem is that BiblePage's "OnNavigatedTo" evento is not triggered so I can't transport my "bible" variable from MainPage to BiblePage.

When I do this procedure outside the splitview's content it works perfectly.

How can I load xaml pages inside my MainPage's splitview content passing parameters?

Comment: MyFrame is where the pages should be hosted. If you do MyFrame.Navigate, does that work?

Comment: No it does not. Actually that's the way it was before. I've changed in a try to get it to work.

Comment: In both ways the page loads but the "OnNavigatedTo" event is not triggered.

Answer (score 4):

Please perform the following test // just tested and didn't get any issue.

1/ MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="App3.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SplitView DisplayMode="Inline" Background="Black" IsPaneOpen="True" OpenPaneLength="360" >
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Button Content="GoToPage" Click="GoToPage_Click" Foreground="White"/>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

2/ MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace App3
{
/// <summary>
/// Une page vide peut être utilisée seule ou constituer une page de destination au sein d'un frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GoToPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), new Params() { MyProperty = 42 });
    }
}

public class Params
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
}
```

3/ SecondPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace App3
{

public sealed partial class SecondPage : Page
{
    public SecondPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Params result = (Params)e.Parameter;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When I do "MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(View.BiblePage), bible)" it navigates to the "BiblePage" and I actually see it on the screen but the BiblePage´s "OnNavigatedTo" event does not get triggered and I do not know why.

If I do the same in a button click event outside the splitview content it wotks perfectly. I see the new screen and it's "OnNavigatedTo" event gets triggered granting me access to the e.parameter that I just passed.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in your BiblePage as the code should work OK.

I created the following GitHub repo based on your code samples: https://github.com/mikoskinen/uwp-frame-datapassing.

If you clone the code and run the app, you can see that the **OnNavigatedTo** is executed and the parameter is passed to the SecondPage correctly. This works in both Windows 10 Mobile Emulator and on local machine.

[image: Debugger]

Couple things to check from your code:

1. Make sure that you create the BiblePage using the **Blank Page template**
2. Make sure that your BiblePage's XAML contains the **x:Class** attribute.

Comment: I found out that if I pass as parameter a single string or a single integer it works perfectly.

But if I pass as parameter the "bible" object the "OnNavigatedTo" event does not get triggered. On the BiblePage I have an object declared with the same type and name that would be used to receive the navigation parameter.

Comment: After trying to fix this for about an hour, #1 solved it perfectly! I was using the "Blank View" template. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First you shoud use `x:Name` instead of `Name` in your XAML to declear a nama of an element.

And since you declear a name in your .xaml, you can directly access it in .xaml.cs by it's name, like:

`var frame=this.MyFrame;`

And importantly, `this.Frame` refers to the `Frame` that hosts this `page`,which  in this case it's `RootFrame`. So here is some key points that helps you:

- A page can place many frames;
- Any frames can be used to navigate to a new page just as: `MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(NewPage),null);`
- So a page could be inside a page;

Comment: I get what you´re saying but what I really need is to access a object that was created in my MainPage (my rootframe) in another xaml page that is going to be loaded into MyFrame.

When I pass the object as an parameter on the "MyFrame.Navigate" I can't access it because the "OnNavigatedTo" event of the xaml loaded does not get triggered.

Comment: If you does navigate to a new page, the 'OnNavigatedTo` method shoud be called in the new page. Make sure you actually navigate to the new page(do you see it from UI?).

Comment: When I do "MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(View.BiblePage), bible)" it navigates to the "BiblePage" and I actually see it on the screen but the BiblePage´s "OnNavigatedTo" event does not get triggered and I do not know why.

If I do the same in a button click outside the splitview content it wotks perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had an piece of code executing on my BiblePage's constructor that was trying to use the variable passed as parameter before it was instanciated by the "OnNavigatedTo" event.

This way I was getting an error on other function before the "OnNavigatedTo" event gets triggered.

Thanks a lot.